# EF 4.4 freeze on large table query

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I m using EF 4.4 on ASP.NET MVC project with SQL server and my below query freeze every run.

`PSSAL` has 426.000 rows and `PU_CustProduct` has 1600 rows

Have any idea or offer for query?

```
  var model = (from p in dbCont.PU_CustProduct
         where !(from pt in dbCont.PSSAL
        where pt.PSSAL_DATE > d1
        && pt.PSSAL_PSPRP_ID == p.CustProductID
        select pt.PSSAL_PSPRP_ID).Contains(p.CustProductID)

     && p.IsActive == true
     && (!p.IsSleepMode == true)
     && p.ProductType == intId
     && p.CustomerID != null
     && p.IsSychSuspend != true

select new WarningViewModel
{
    PrpName = p.LicenceName,
    CrmID = p.CustomerID.ToString(),
    PsprpId = p.CustProductID.ToString(),
}).Distinct().OrderBy(o => o.PrpName).ToList();
```

Comment: Why are there so many parameters you need to check against? Wouldn't `(!p.IsSleepMode == true)` be the same as `p.IsSleepMode == false`?

Comment: Post up the generated SQL for review. Using either SQL profiler or something like EF profiler.

Comment: How long does it take if you execute the generated query manually using query profiler?

Comment: DaveHogan, it is ok after generated sql, thanks.